# grails upload Groovy script and run it

Tags: grails

I am wanting to know if it is possible to upload a groovy script to a grails application and for it to be run, using the grails applications dependencies.

I cannot think of a way to day this, can anyone advise.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do that using GroovyShell, GrailsAwareClassLoader, CompilationUnit. Could you be more specific regarding what actualy you want to accomplish and what is the approach that you are thinking of?

Comment: Just read Groovy documentation: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_integrating_groovy_in_a_java_application

Comment: I'm a big fan of the [Console](https://grails.org/plugin/console) plugin; allows you to run Groovy scripts and has access to domain classes, application context, etc.